# Unable to import react-native-vector-icons using es6

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-native

I'm trying to use [`react-native-vector-icons`](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) with ES6 in React Native, but unfortunately I'm having trouble importing the icons. Their documentation still uses the old `require` statement, so I don't think it's helpful.

This is my import:

```
import {Ionicons} from './node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons.js';
```

This is my usage:

```
<Ionicons name="ios-book" color="#4F8EF7" />
```

The error I receive is:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

It's clear that `Ionicons` is undefined, so I'm aware that fundamental about the import statement is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

Comment: I'm surprised to say that this actually works. I didn't know that it was possible to do that. Thank you for your answer as well!

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

`import {x} from 'abc';` translates to `var x=require('abc').x`, not to `var x=require('abc')`.

So what about :

```
import * as Ionicons from './node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons.js';
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I still get the same error message, but this time Ionicons is an *object* type. This doesn't make sense to me since Ionicons.js' module.export is something that was made with React.createClass(), but that's too much for this question. I appreciate the help!

Comment: This does not work: var Icon = require('react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons');
but this does: import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an import statement as follows:

```
import {default as Icon} from '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

This is because after I followed @Olivier's advice, I ended up with an object that contained a number of properties and I couldn't just use `<Icon>` as a component, but I discovered that `<Icon.default>` worked.

Thanks to all who answered!

Comment: Strange, It's 2018 and I have the same problem. Tried all the proposed solutions but only yours is working.